# How to set a Dynamics CRM/365 field with Base64String value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I want to set the "base64string" with the base 64 string value of a document, then I will later take that value and load the document onto sharepoint(I already have the c# code for this working through a console application).

My code below does not seem to work, basically the value is never set, The field base64string is a multi-line with 1 million characters.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  Please select a file and then hit Evaluate:
  <br/>
  <input id="file" type="file" />
  <button id="button">Upload        
    <script>           
      document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var files = document.getElementById('file').files;
        if (files.length > 0) {
          getBase64(files[0]);
        }
      });

      function getBase64(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function () {        
          Xrm.Page.getAttribute("base64string").setValue(reader.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {};
      }        
    </script>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you placing this code?

Comment: @JamesWood the code is placed as a WebResource on the campaign form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("base64string")`, are you certain `base64string` is a field name? If its a custom field it should have a prefix such as `abc_base64string`.

Furthermore a HTML web resouce can't directly access `Xrm.Page`.

[Reference other web resources from an HTML web resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309536.aspx#Reference%20other%20web%20resources%20from%20an%20HTML%20web%20resource).

> An HTML web resource added to a form can’t use global objects defined
>   by the JavaScript library loaded in the form. An HTML web resource may
>   interact with the **Xrm.Page** or **Xrm.Utility** objects within the form by
>   using **parent.Xrm.Page** or **parent.Xrm.Utility**, but global objects
>   defined by form scripts won’t be accessible using the parent.

I belive your code should look more like this:

```
reader.onload = function () {        
    parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("abc_base64string").setValue(reader.result);
};
```